# simple list in python trying to make new line between

Tags: python

```
r=[]  
x='hi'  
y='there'  
z='how are you?'  
for i in range(4):  
    r.append(x)
    r.append(y)
    r.append('\n')
    r.append(z)
print(r)
```

Current result:

```
['hi', 'there', '\n', 'how are you ?', 'hi', 'there', '\n', 'how are you ?', 'hi', 'there', '\n', 'how are you ?', 'hi', 'there', '\n', 'how are you ?']
```

It's not going to a new line. Can anyone help me with this simple program?

Expected output:

```
hi there  
how are you?   
hi there  
how are you?  
...
```

Comment: You code won't work for missing `:`. Edit it. And do you want to print the result?

Comment: i had the : in pycharm forgot to type it here

Comment: `print(' '.join(r))`

Comment: @timmy you can copy the code rather than re-typing you know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate the strings to an output string rather than appending to a list:

```
output = ''
x = 'hi'  
y = 'there'  
z = 'how are you?'  
for i in range(4):  
    output += x + ' ' + y + '\n' + z + '\n'
print(output)
```

which gives:

```
hi there
how are you?
hi there
how are you?
hi there
how are you?
hi there
how are you?
```

Comment: Appending to a list and the calling str.join at the end is more efficient though

Comment: @Chris_Rands But its awkward because the new-lines will be padded with spaces so each line will begin with a space.

Answer (score 0):

You need append another newline character at the end of the loop and use join method to print your result

```
r=[]  
x='hi'  
y='there'  
z='how are you?'  
for i in range(4):  
    r.append(x)
    r.append(y)
    r.append('\n')
    r.append(z)
    r.append('\n')
print(r)
print(" ".join(r))
```

#### Output

> hi there
>     how are you?
>     hi there
>     how are you?
>     hi there
>     how are you?
>     hi there
>     how are you?

Comment: I agree with this. But a slight detail is that there is a whitespace before each new line. But I don't really see the use case for this question anyways.

Comment: ty for answer can i ask exactly how does the print(" ".join(r)) work?

Comment: @timmy it iterates over the iterable (e.g. list) `r` and puts the seperator (in this case the whitespace) between each element and the result is one string

Comment: @FrederikPetersen ty very much